# Cannot import WSDL service "targetNamespace 'urn:webservice' not found'

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl

The last couple of hours I've been struggling with importing a WSDL webservice into Visual Studio 2010. Slowly I've been struggling through my WSDL, solving other problems untill I encountered this one:

```
Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: 
System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace 'urn:WebService' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source:
//wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:WebService']/wsdl:portType[@name='DataPort']   
C:\* blablabla *\WeGotchaService\Reference.svcmap   1   1   Gotcha!
```

I've tried every tiny little thing Google could provide me with including:

1. Disable 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies'
2. Set Collection type to system.collections.generic.list
3. Changing a large part of the attributes back and forth.
4. Copying a WSDL file from someone else, just to see if it would work (it didn't)

Here is my .wsdl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions 
  name="WebService"
  targetNamespace="urn:WebService" 
  xmlns:tns="urn:WebService"  
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

  <types>
     <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="GetData">
      <xsd:element name="getCustomerID" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="DataResponse" type="xsd:string" />
     </xsd:schema>
  </types>

  <message name="doGetCustomerID">
    <part name="ID" type="tns:getCustomerID" />
  </message>

  <message name="doDataResponse">
    <part name="return" type="tns:DataResponse" />
  </message>

  <portType name="DataPort">
    <operation name="getData">
      <input message="tns:doGetCustomerID" />
      <output message="tns:doDataResponse" />
    </operation>
  </portType>

  <binding name="DataBinding" type="tns:DataPort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="getData">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getDataAction" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:GetData"     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:GetData" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>

  <service name="WeGotchaService">
     <port name="DataPort" binding="tns:DataBinding">
       <soap:address location="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler.php" />
     </port>
  </service>

</definitions>
```

Servicehandler.php

```
<?php
if(!extension_loaded("soap"))
{
  dl("php_soap.dll");
}

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$server = new SoapServer("getPersonen.wsdl");

function getData($persoon_id)
{
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db('gotcha_dbtemplate');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lessen";
$sql = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  $result[] = $row;
}
mysql_close();

  return $result;
}

$server->addFunction("getData");
$server->handle();
?>
```

I don't know how to fix this. There are some other errors but these are due to the fact that it has trouble importing the portType (binding import error because portType is not okay, port error because dependant on binding)

I hope someone knows what the problem is, I don't :(
Thanks.

**Update:** my test.php does work okay and it does output the results from the getData method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed so much I can't exactly remember, now it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns:tns="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/wsdl_service.wsdl"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="WebService" targetNamespace="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/wsdl_service.wsdl">
<types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/wsdl_service.wsdl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/wsdl_service.wsdl">
        <xsd:element name="getCustomerID" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xs:complexType name="Persoon">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xsd:int"/>
                <xs:element name="Voornaam" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Achternaam" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Adres" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Postcode" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Woonplaats" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Email_adres" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Telefoonnummer" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xs:element name="CBR_Kandidaatnummer" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Rijbewijs" type="xsd:int"/>
                <xs:element name="Laatste_keer_bewerkt" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="PersoonList">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Persoon" type="tns:Persoon" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
</types>
<message name="doGetCustomerID">
    <part name="CustomerID" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="doGetPersoonDataResponse">
    <part name="return" type="tns:PersoonList"/>
</message>
<portType name="DataPort">
    <operation name="getPersoonData">
        <input message="tns:doGetCustomerID"/>
        <output message="tns:doGetPersoonDataResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="DataBinding" type="tns:DataPort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="getPersoonData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getDataAction"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:GetData"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:GetData"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="WeGotchaService">
    <port name="DataPort" binding="tns:DataBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/servicehandler.php"/>
    </port>
</service>
```